# WPF Master -Detail Binding XElement

Tags: wpf, binding, master-detail, xelement

I have a XElement that has the following structure

```
<document num="1">
 <pages>
   <page />
   <page />
 </pages>
 </document/>
```

I have one Listbox named "documents" that is bound to an XElement in the following manner:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TheXElement.Elements[document]}"
```

I want to have a second ListBox named "pages" whose ItemsSource is the pages based on the selected document in the first list box.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=documents,Path=SelectedItem.Element[pages].Elements[page]}"
```

Of source ,the above statement does not work.
When I try the following
`ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=documents,Path=SelectedItem}`,
the "pages" ListBox does get bound to the correct document, but it gets a binding error "ReferenceConverter cannot convert from System.Xml.Linq.XElement"

I think I'm close, but having issues getting it to work.
How can I correctly bind the "pages" ListBox to the SelectedItem of the "documents" ListBox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, using a custom converter

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771571.aspx